# hot to adapt an angular loading spinner to work on 'post' requests in addition to 'get'

Tags: angularjs

I came across this plunker, demonstrating angular loading spinner: http://plnkr.co/edit/PUjrEIt0YLTwr0rUInv8?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Loading Spinner Demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-spinner.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-loading-spinner.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}"></span>
  <button ng-click="startAjax()">Start Ajax Call</button>
  <p>
    <b>Spinner Active: </b>
    {{spinnerActive}}
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This appears to work well for http get requests, but, in my case, I need it also to work for http post - i.e. give the user a 'busy' indication while my http post is doing its thing.
Once my angular controller gets the '201' back from the server, I need to hide the spinner.

Here is the angular-loading-spinner directive:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('ngLoadingSpinner', ['angularSpinner'])
    .directive('usSpinner',   ['$http', '$rootScope' ,function ($http, $rootScope){
        return {
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
            {
                $rootScope.spinnerActive = false;
                scope.isLoading = function () {
                    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
                };

                scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (loading)
                {
                    $rootScope.spinnerActive = loading;
                    if(loading){
                        elm.removeClass('ng-hide');
                    }else{
                        elm.addClass('ng-hide');
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    }]);
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have anything to do. The directive looks for http pending requests, and those include post requests. Just modify the plunkr and make it use post instead of get, and you'll see that it works fine.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/Bd7LO0IgrI0wLYOapJCy?p=preview, where I just changed

```
$http.get('your-server-endpoint')
```

into

```
$http.post('your-server-endpoint')
```

Comment: This is strange. In my code I already have: $http.post('/salesforce_update', json)

Comment: I think, I will just look for a simple spinner, which I can control with ng-show="some_indicator"

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg (Realizing I'm zombie threading a little) Does that mean you weren't able to get your code to work? Did you figure out why it didn't?